# How to run tests multiple times with different system property values in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'd like to know how to run my test suite in Gradle twice, with different values set for a system property. Right now I can set a system property using e.g.:

```
test {
    systemProperty "org.d2ab.sequence.strict", "true"
}
```

But how can I set the property to false and run the test suite again?

Comment: One doesn't run it's test twice, one write two distinctive test cases.

Comment: The property I'm setting determines the behaviour of pretty much the entire test suite, and it should pass for both settings, so I'd like to test it with both settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another [Test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) task.

```
test {
    systemProperty "org.d2ab.sequence.strict", "true"
}
task test2(type: Test) {
    systemProperty "org.d2ab.sequence.strict", "false"
} 
check.dependsOn test2
```

See [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L196) to see where the default test task is added by the `java` plugin.

Comment: Coming from a Maven world that just feels way too easy. :-)

Comment: Haha.. you're in for some more pleasant surprises in the future I'm sure