# How to pass set of Systemproperties only to one particular testcase instead of all in gradle test

Tags: eclipse, gradle, junit

I have set of Junit test suites. All are working fine in eclipse.
In the test suites one test suite we will pass some System properties.
But those modified system properties should not propagate to other test suites So i just put those only in setup method like below,

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("public", "publicfolder");
        System.setProperty("private", "privatefolder");
    }
```

But this is working fine in eclipse only. While running it outside all other test suites are working fine except the above one.
I know to pass system properties in gradle in build file. but how could i pass those system properties to only one test suite instead of all thats my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another `Test` task so there's two in total. Each could have a different filter to run separate test suites and each could pass different system properties.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41664097/1089967) for a similar solution